# chainlink docker to postgres docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, chainlink

I am trying to connect chainlink to the postgres db and for the same I am running both of them as docker images.

I start the postgres docker as:

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

This starts the postgres successfully.

However if I try to connect chainlink (as per the [chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/) doc) using the below .env
file

```
ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=5
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
ETH_URL=wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/<API KEY>
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://some-postgres:secret@postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
```

I am trying to connect to the "some-postgres" instance with the password as "secret" and still it throws the error

```
Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=postgres user=some-postgres database=postgres`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 172.17.0.3:47766->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout)                                  err=Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=postgres user=some-postgres database=postgres`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 172.17.0.3:47766->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout) errVerbose=opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=postgres user=some-postgres database=postgres`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 172.17.0.3:47766->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout)
Cannot boot Chainlink
```

I don't know why it does not connect chainlink docker to postgres docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ZeusLawyer Thanks. In the meantime I got it working with the below config, if it helps  others.

```
# to start db instance
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 5432:5432 -d postges:latest
```

For Chainlink instance

```
docker run --network=host -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-goerli:/chainlink -it --env-file=chainlink.env smartcontract/chainlink:1.5.0-root local n -p /chainlink/password.txt -a /chainlink/apicredentials.txt
```

DATABASE_URL

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://root:secret@localhost:5432/root?sslmode=disable
```

Comment: perfect - yes the volume mapping needs to be done too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `DATABASE_URL` env var is not composed correctly?

As per the Chainlink Docs you referenced, the DB connection string should follow this format:
`"DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER:$PORT/$DATABASE"`

I think you've put `user-postgres` as your username when it may actually be the server name?

the Postgres database user name and password can be set directly in your DATABASE_URL connection string and then you may not need to pass it in your `docker run` command.

But first be sure you know the username and password (refer to [these docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/connecting-to-a-remote-database/)) and the Postgres docker documentation.

Then fill in your connection string carefully using the format provided in the docs.